# UTF-8 character encoding battles json_encode()

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, character-encoding, json

**Quest**

I am looking to fetch rows that have accented characters. The encoding for the column (`NAME`) is `latin1_swedish_ci`.

**The Code**

The following query returns `Abord â Plouffe` using phpMyAdmin:

```
SELECT C.NAME FROM CITY C
WHERE C.REGION_ID=10 AND C.NAME_LOWERCASE LIKE '%abor%'
ORDER BY C.NAME LIMIT 30
```

The following displays expected values (function is called `db_fetch_all( $result )`):

```
  while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result ) ) {
    foreach( $row as $value ) {
      echo $value . " ";
      $value = utf8_encode( $value );
      echo $value . " ";
    }

    $r[] = $row;
  }
```

The displayed values: `5482 5482 Abord â Plouffe Abord Ã¢ Plouffe`

The array is then encoded using `json_encode`:

```
$rows = db_fetch_all( $result );
echo json_encode( $rows );
```

**Problem**

The web browser receives the following value:

```
{"ID":"5482","NAME":null}
```

Instead of:

```
{"ID":"5482","NAME":"Abord â Plouffe"}
```

(Or the encoded equivalent.)

**Question**

The documentation states that `json_encode()` works on UTF-8. I can see the values being encoded from LATIN1 to UTF-8. After the call to `json_encode()`, however, the value becomes `null`.

How do I make `json_encode()` encode the UTF-8 values properly?

One possible solution is to use the [Zend Framework](http://www.zfforums.com/zend-framework-general-discussions-1/general-q-zend-framework-2/json-encoding-breaks-strings-containing-special-characters-210.html), but I'd rather not if it can be avoided.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

```
// Create an empty array for the encoded resultset
$rows = array();

// Loop over the db resultset and put encoded values into $rows
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  $rows[] = array_map('utf8_encode', $row);
}

// Output $rows
echo json_encode($rows);
```

Answer (score 12):

```
foreach( $row as $value ) {
  $value = utf8_encode( $value );
```

You're not actually writing your encoded value back into the `$row` array there, you're only changing the local variable `$value`. If you want to write back when you change the variable, you would need to treat it as a reference:

```
foreach( $row as &$value ) {
```

Personally I would try to avoid references where possible, and for this case instead use `array_map` as posted by Kemo.

Or `mysql_set_charset` to UTF-8 to get the return values in UTF-8 regardless of the actual table collations, as a first step towards migrating the app to UTF-8.

Answer (score 5):

My solution is insert this line `mysql_query('SET CHARACTER SET utf8');`, before the `SELECT`.
This method is good.

Answer (score 4):

It seems that rather than putting it in a query, one should put:

```
mysql_set_charset('utf8');
```

after the mysql connect statement.

Answer (score 1):

In your connect: `mysql_set_charset('utf8', $link);`

Example:

```
<?php
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'your_user', 'your_password');
mysql_set_charset('utf8', $link);
$db_selected = mysql_select_db('your_db', $link);
...
```

Hope that helps somewhat.

Answer (score 1):

Try `iconv_r($row,"LATIN1","UTF-8//TRANSLIT");` (function below) before you `json_encode()` your result.

I have UTF-8 as the table encoding and as the result set encoding, but sometimes folks still manage to submit non-UTF-8 characters via forms and it's troublesome to track down every single input source so I have also wrapped `json_encode()` to make it safer.  In particular I've had it NULL strings on me containing the degree symbol and "smart quotes" which folks in the UK seem so fond of.

```
function safe_json_encode($mixed,$missing="TRANSLIT"){
   $out=json_encode($mixed);
   if ($err=  json_last_error()){
      iconv_r("UTF-8","UTF-8//$missing",$mixed);
      $out=json_encode($mixed);
   }
   return $out;
}
function iconv_r($charset_i, $charset_o, &$mixed) {
   if (is_string($mixed)) {
      $mixed = iconv($charset_i, $charset_o, $mixed);
   } else {
      if (is_object($mixed)){
         $mixed = (array) $mixed;
      }
      if (is_array($mixed)){
         foreach ($mixed as $key => &$value) {
            iconv_r($charset_i, $charset_o, $value);
         }
      }
   }
}
```