# json_encoded String that cannot appear to be decoded

Tags: json

I have successfully produced the json representation below for one custom object.  However, when I use json_decode(jsonObjectBelow) I am not successfully in converting it to an array. I have finally found out why this has happened.  If I delete characters with accents e.g  "Muñoz-Gómez", then the json_decode(jsonObjectBelow) works, and I am able to generate my array and extract the attributes.  For practical purposes, I cannot scour all the attributes and removing these accents...Is there a solution?

```
json_object received: [{"abstractText":"Fevers of unknown origin (FUOs) may be due to any of over 200 different disorders. We present a most unusual case of an FUO in a returning traveler from the Dominican Republic. Work-up for Q fever, Brucellosis, Bartonella, malaria and HIV were negative, but very highly elevated ESRs and ferritin levels suggested possible Legionnaire\u0027s disease. This is the third reported case of Legionnaire\u0027s disease presenting as an FUO.","authorString":"Muñoz-Gómez S, Cunha BA.","issue":"1","journalTitle":"Heart Lung","pageInfo":"72-74","pmid":"25444558","pubYear":"2015","title":"Fever of unknown origin (FUO) due to Legionnaire\u0027s disease.","volume":"44"}]
```

This code works for text in attributes that have not got accents, but does not work for text with accents.
My php code:

```
     //Get JSON POST
       $json = $_POST["jsonObj"];

     //Decode JSON into an Array
      $data = json_decode($json);

     for($i = 0; $i<count($data); $i++){

     echo "[".$i."]" . " " .$data[$i]->authorString . "/  " . $data[$i]->journalTitle . "<br>";
     }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4077088/1169798 may be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

if possible try to encode the values and the send the json object. Try the steps in the following link:

[UTF-8 character encoding battles json_encode()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2790027/utf-8-character-encoding-battles-json-encode)