# unknown error when trying to read json_encode data from PDO FetchAll Query

Tags: php, jquery, json, pdo

I'm trying to manage data from a php function in JSON, but when I try to Access it, my Ajax always goes to error method.

My PHP Function:

```
function retornarPreguntas()
{
    try {
        global $conexion;
        $query = $conexion->query('SELECT idPreguntas, Pregunta, Categoria, Visible, formato FROM preguntas');
        $query->execute();
        $preguntas = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        header('Content-type:application/json;charset=utf-8');  
        $json = json_encode($preguntas);
        echo $json;
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }   
}
```

my JQuery Function

```js
            function crearPreguntas() {
              $.ajax({
                url: "includes/RespuestasAjax.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: {
                  funcion: "retornarPreguntas"
                },
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(data) {
                  var html = "<tr><td colspan='5' align='center'>Evaluación</td></tr>";
                  html += '<tr><td colspan="5" align="center">Factores Generales de desempeño y rendimiento</td></tr>';
                  //var factores = retornarFactores();
                  alert("uno");
                  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    html += '<tr>';
                    html += '<td>' + data[i]['pregunta'] + '</td>';
                    html += '<td><select id="pregunta' + i + '">';
                    for (k = 1; k <= 5; k++) {
                      html += '<option value="' + k + '">' + k + '</option>';
                    }
                    html += '</tr>';
                  }
                  $('#preguntas').empty();
                  $('#preguntas').append(html);
                },
                error: function(codigo) {
                  console.log(codigo);
                }
              });
            }
```

If I change my PHP function to print_r my alert display the data, but I can't Access by key index, if I try json then it gives me the error:

> [object Object]{readyState: 4, responseText: "", status: 200, statusText: "OK"}

Any idea of what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The Ajax request with `dataType: json` throws an error when Your reponse cannot be parsed as `JSON` so please check if you are able to `json_encode` the data correctly and check your query.

Comment: Check the network tab of the console, if you have error reporting enabled in your php script, and a notice or warning is being generated, that will be echoed out before the json and  invalidate it causing this error. I bet you have something like `Notice: Undefined variable: ....`

Comment: jQuery's `error` callback has more info than what you are showing.  Change the `error` callback to `error: function(jqXHR, status, error){ console.log(status, error); }`.

Comment: "SyntaxError: Error de sintaxis
   at m.parseJSON (http://localhost/RRHH/assets/js/jquery.min.js:5:15984)
   at Pb (http://localhost/RRHH/assets/js/jquery.min.js:5:18377)
   at x (http://localhost/RRHH/assets/js/jquery.min.js:5:21791)
   at b (http://localhost/RRHH/assets/js/jquery.min.js:5:26030)"

Comment: I notice that you are  setting `data: { funcion: "retornarPreguntas" }`  in your ajax (note the misspelling of `function`) If your php file does something like `$function = $_POST['data']['function'];` that would cause this error because `$function` would be undefined, you would need to fix the misspelling and should instead write that more like `$data= isset($_POST['data']['function']) ? $_POST['data']['function'] : null;` to avoid the warning if the value doesn't exist

Comment: @GlacialVoid: Either you're getting a `PDOException`, so it's printing the `"Error:"` or you're printing something else before/after the JSON data.  Or, maybe your query is returning 0 rows.

Comment: @DelightedD0D funcion is the spanish of function, I'm using that as post to use it in a switch(funcion) { case 'retornarPreguntas' : retornarPreguntas(); break; } I think I know why the json has error, my Query has a text field with questions that contains comma, maybe that's the problem.

Comment: Fair enough, I'm pretty sure json_encode takes care of the comas though. Did you look at the network tab in the console? if there is an error, outside the json itself, it will be very evident

Comment: @DelightedD0D after all this, I excluded the "pregunta" column from my query and error is gone, maybe there's a special character or something that json_encode doesn't like. My field has: utf8_general_ci and DB: utf8mb4_general_ci. For example: "Aplica los conceptos, técnicas y procedimientos que conoce, en la realización de su trabajo." this breaks the json_encode because acute accent, some even have ñ.

Comment: Try putting `echo json_last_error();` right after your `json_encode`. What message does that give?

Comment: @DelightedD0D error code 5

Comment: Ok, that means "5 = JSON_ERROR_UTF8    Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded" The issue is likely the accents used in the spanish questions. [See this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2790027/utf-8-character-encoding-battles-json-encode)

Answer (score 0):

I just added this to my php code:

```
$preguntas = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
header('Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8');
$json = json_encode($preguntas);
```

Instead of:

```
$preguntas = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
**header('Content-type:application/json;charset=utf-8');**  
$json = json_encode($preguntas);
```

Comment: And...?  Did that solve it?  Is this an *answer* to the question?

Comment: Yeah it did, well I also added to my connection string this: ;charset=utf8mb4'