# PHP Json Encode PDO::FETCH_ASSOC

Tags: php, json, pdo

I'm attempting to return all the rows of my MSSQL database table and spit them out in a JSON_ENCODE.

**When I use this and echo the $json I get a blank page. When I do a var_dump on that var I get a bool, false.**

```
$sth = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM dbo.Devices");
$sth->execute();

$array = $sth->fetchAll( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );
$json = json_encode($array);
```

**However, if I was to place the same fetchAll into a result var and print it, it works fine!**

```
Working using print function.
$result = $sth->FetchAll();
print_r($result);
```

I've read of others having similar issues and that it was a UTF8 encoding issue so I attempted to do a utf8_encode on the $array before a json_encode but with the same result of a blank page. Can anyone explain this?

Comment: You don't use `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` in the second example. Does removing that option allow you to `json_encode()` the result?

Comment: No, I get a blank page when removing that as well.

Comment: Wait, are you getting a blank page because you're not printing out the json_encoded results?  `print_r` prints to screen, `json_encode` does not.

Comment: I'm doing an echo on the results.

Comment: Why do you think it's an encoding issue? What does your data look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`json_encode` is character encoding sensitive. It will fail if it can't handle the encoding. `print_r` is not. It will happily print out whatever you give it.

The `utf8_encode` fix will only work if the strings in your source data are encoded as ISO-8859-1. Assuming that's true it should work. Make sure you do it like this... https://stackoverflow.com/a/2790107/111755