# Mssql result json_encode not returning anything php pdo

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo, special-characters

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [acctcode] => 631
            [description] => Blood Transfussion Set, Blood Transfusion Set- ADULT
            [pchrgqty] => 1.00
            [pchrgup] => 17.00
            [pcchrgamt] => 17.00
            [patlast] => GUADA�A
            [patfirst] => FRITZIE ELINE
            [patmiddle] => DAYTEC
            [patsuffix] => 
        )

)
```

The above array in php is result of `print_r($result);` now this array will be json_encoded as below:

```
echo json_encode($result, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

I am encoding this because it is for ajax request. Now in echo part it is not returning anything. I dont know why this is happening but my guess is because of 
`“Ñ”` which is in the `[patlast] => GUADA�A` and is shown as `�`. I am getting this result set in a select of `MSSQL DATABASE`.

> How to handle this result set in MSSQL and be able to return the correct data.

Comment: Have you tried UTF-8 encoding it?

Comment: i have tried adding UTF-8 in header but it didnt solve the problem i did more digging and found the best solution below credit goes to Kemo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the best solution for my project in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2790027/utf-8-character-encoding-battles-json-encode)

Using below code:

```
// Create an empty array for the encoded resultset

$rows = array();

// Loop over the db resultset and put encoded values into $rows

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  $rows[] = array_map('utf8_encode', $row);
}

// Output $rows

echo json_encode($rows);
```

The answer was given my user ***Kemo***